# Probability of getting 2 head and 2 tail

Tags: probability

If a fair coin is tossed 4 times what is the probability that two heads and two tails will result ?

My calculation is.
no. of ways of getting exactly 2 head and 2 tails .will be $6$ out of $8$.
Eg $$HHTT,THHT,TTHH,HTTH,HTHT,THTH,HHHT,TTTH$$

Comment: You mean, 6 out of 16, right?

Comment: There are $16$ equally probable possible throws.  Of these $\binom 42=6$ will have exactly two $H's$.

Comment: ... don't forget $HHTH, HTHH, THHH, TTHT, THTT, HTTT, HHHH, TTTT$

Comment: $$HHHH,HHHT,HHTH,HTHH,THHH , TTTT , TTTH , TTHT ,THTT,HTTT,\color{red}{HHTT,HTHT,HTTH,TTHH,THTH,THHT}$$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let the random variable $X$ be the number of heads that come up when a fair coin is tossed $4$ times. Then $X \sim B\left(4, \frac{1}{2}\right)$.

We want there to be exactly two heads (forcing the other two tosses to be tails), so $$\mathbb{P}(X = 2) = \binom{4}{2} \left(\frac{1}{2}\right)^2 \left(\frac{1}{2}\right)^2 = \frac{3}{8}.$$

Answer (score 0):

There are $2^4=16$ possible outcomes:

$HHHH$ $\ \ $ $HHHT$ $\ \ $ $HHTH$ $\ \ $ $HTHH$ $\ \ $ $THHH$ $\ \ $ $\color{red}{HHTT}$ $\ \ $ $\color{red}{HTHT}$ $\ \ $ $\color{red}{THHT}$ $\ \ $ $\color{red}{HTTH}$ $\ \ $ $\color{red}{THHT}$ $\ \ $  $\color{red}{TTHH}$ $\ \ $ $HTTT$ $\ \ $ $THTT$ $\ \ $ $TTHT$ $\ \ $ $TTTH$ $\ \ $ $TTTT$ $\ \ $

6 of them have 2 tails and 2 heads. Thus the probability of getting 2 heads and 2 tails is

$\frac {\text{No. of favorable outcomes}}{\text{No. of possible outcomes}}=\frac{6}{16}=\frac38$